# How do you replace multiple instances of a preg_match matches with different replacement text?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a script that runs through text input by a user and replaces text contained in tags with html. It mostly works fine however one of the tags is giving me trouble.

[include=someFile.php] should load the contents of someFile.php into the page, [inlude=thatFile.txt] should load thatFile.txt. However, when there are multiple instances of the include tag, each one referring to different files, it is replacing them all with just one of the included files. The code I am using is this...

```
if (preg_match ("/\[include=(.+?)\]/", $text, $matches)) {
  foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $match = preg_replace("/\[include=/", "", $match);
    $match = preg_replace("/\]/", "", $match);
    $include = $match;
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($include);
    $text = preg_replace("/\[include=(.+?)\]/", "$file_contents", $text);
  }
}
```

The last line of the foreach loop seems to be replacing every instance of the matched tags with whatever it finds in the current tag but I don't know what to do about it. Any advice appreciated!

Edit: Thanks to Uby I made the following changes and it works now.

```
if (preg_match_all ("/\[include=(.+?)\]/", $text, $matches)) {

    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        $file = preg_replace("/\[include=/", "", $match);
        $file = preg_replace("/\]/", "", $file);
        $file_contents = file_get_contents($file);
        $text = str_replace("$match", "$file_contents", $text);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_match()` will match just one occurrence, in your case you should use `preg_match_all()` (see documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Read carefully the documentation, your loop wouldn't work like this.

Comment: Thanks Uby, that was the info I needed